# What indoor environments are available in the GTA Creator?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, grand-theft-auto-content-creator

I've seen a number of user created GTA Online capture/ deathmatch missions that take place inside buildings.

Most of these seem to be made by using exploits.

Without using exploits what indoor environments are available in the GTA Creator?

The only indoor environment I know of is the derelict motel in Sandy Shores.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good list of GTA indoor environments here: http://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/1p0r07/gta_online_known_interiorenterable_locations_with/

Unfortunately testing in the Creator suggests that most of these places are "restricted" so capture objects, player start positions etc. cannot be place inside them.